# How to generate random name in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to generate a random name that will be used in the HTTP request in Jmeter for my APIs performance testing. The name would get changed for every thread.

**format : "gpt_OverTimePayUsage_<some_random_number>"**

The <some_random_number> would change as the thread would change.

I thought of using the JSR2223 pre-processor for each HTTP request and using Java as the language. But I am not sure how to go forward.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is just using [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like:

```
${__Random(1111111111111111111,9223372036854775806,)}
```

[image]

JSR223 PreProcessor can be used as well, but in this case consider using [Groovy as the language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as `java` is not the real Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter and [using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)